# Declare type on prototype using typescript

Tags: typescript, prototype

I am using Vue, and I have added an object to `Vue.prototype`:

```
Vue.prototype.$rpc = ...;
```

I declare this in `rpc.d.ts`:

```
import MyRpc from "./MyRpc";

declare module "vue/types/vue" {
  interface Vue {
    $rpc?: MyRpc;
  }
}
```

And then I use it in another file:

```
import "./rpc";

...

if (Vue.prototype.$rpc !== undefined) {
  Vue.prototype.$rpc.foo();
}
```

However, the type for `Vue.prototype` and `Vue.prototype.$rpc` are both `any`. Why doesn't Typescript know about my type? If I do:

```
new Vue().$rpc
```

Then it is typed correctly. But I don't want to create an object to access `$rpc`.

And yes I realise this is more or less equivalent to a plain global variable, which I may end up switching to.

Comment: If this question is Vue-specific you might want to tag it.  Otherwise, you might want to make the code here a [mcve] with no external dependencies.  Good luck!

Comment: It's not Vue-specific.

Comment: Then please consider editing the above code to something without such a dependency.  Ideally someone could drop example code into an IDE and immediately reproduce your issue so they can make suggestions.